# Spawning external processes from Jenkins - spawned but not executing

Tags: python, jenkins

I am attempting to launch a couple of external applications from a Jenkins build step in Windows 7 64-bit. They are essentially programs designed to interact with each other and perform a series of regression tests on some software. Jenkins is run as Windows service as a user with admin privileges on the machine. I think that's full disclosure on any weirdness with my Jenkins installation.

I have written a Python3 script that successfully does what I want it to when run from the Windows command line. When when I run this script as a Jenkins build step, I can see that the applications have been spawned via the Task Manager, but there is no CPU activity associated with them, and no other evidence that they are actually doing anything (they produce log files, etc., but none of these appear). One of the applications typically runs at 25% CPU during the course of the regression tests.

The Python script itself runs to completion as if everything is OK. Jenkins is correctly monitoring the output of the script, which I can watch from the job's console output. I'm using os.spawnv(os.P_NOWAIT, ...) for each of the external application. The subprocess module doesn't do what I want it to, I just want these programs to run externally.

I've even run a bash script via Cygwin that functionally does the same thing as the Python script with the same results. Any idea why these applications spawn but don't execute?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. You say `they produce log files, etc., but none of these appear`. What is in these log files and where should they appear? `The Python script itself runs to completion as if everything is OK`. So where exactly is the problem? Could you please be more precise, what functionality you are missing? Otherwise I think noone can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the external applications i spawn from the build step are spawned (i.e. they appear in the Task Manager) but never do anything. They should immediately begin running regression tests with no user interaction required, which will immediately produce a log file. The log file would be produced in a subdirectory of the application's installation. (This is outside of C:\Program Files)

Comment: I've actually just (sort of) figured it out. I stopped Jenkins and set it to run as the Local System user with Desktop interaction. After restarting, I reran the Python script and it appears to be working. I guess Jenkins doesn't like being run as a system user.